# Is CyanogenMod available in several languages?

Tags: cyanogenmod, languages

Vanilla Android works in so many languages (including mine). What about Cyanogen? Are there language packs? I have not found any on official site, but maybe anything unofficial?

And if there is/isn't any, then

- Is the translation device-specific?
- Will some parts of system, that come from original (vanilla) Android work in my local language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CyanogenMod ROMs are multilingual and you can select the language the first time your phone boots or in `System settings-->Language & input-->Language`(ICS 4.0.4) at any time.

I can say it supports all languages in the world from The far East to South America including right to left languages like Farsi.

Answer (score 3):

All officially supported languages are listed on their changelog: https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_vendor_cyanogen/blob/gingerbread/CHANGELOG.mkdn